# Drupal 6: Menu and taxonomy name mismatch

Tags: taxonomy-terms, routes

The error log on my drupal 6 site displays the message "Menu and taxonomy name mismatch: Gerona (42) != Gerona (7)"
I looked it up and apparantely it is a taxonomy menu - i18n problem, they don't get along... does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: it might be of help for you
http://drupal.org/node/316632#comment-1441076

Comment: The issue you linked has been marked as fixed on May 1, 2010. I don't think it is the same issue, if the OP is using the latest version of the module.

Comment: What version of that module are you using? Is it version 6.x-2.9, the development snapshot, or any other version?

Comment: It is the 6.x-2.9

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as kiamlaluno.